# Counting option in a select after modifying using .html()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Synopsis:

I have an on change event on a element that triggers a few things,

1. First an ajax call that returns a string containing html options.
2. I then insert those options into  a dropdown like so:
   selectObject.empty().html( optionString );
3. This seems to work fine, But, here is the potential for the option string to only contain one blank/empty option.If that occurs I need to hide the dropdown. So (in a separate function) I attempt to count the options in the select after the modification it like so:

`var numberOfOptions = $('#id_of_select').children('option').length;`

The issue is that this count returns the number of options BEFORE it was modified. It doesn't recognize the added html yet.

Any advice/solutions?

Comment: Your code works, but ajax is asynchronous, you have to wait for the result and the inserted elements before you can check the length

Comment: Where are you counting the options ?? Inside the ajax or after ajax ? If you count after ajax, then it will return the count before the select tag is appended inside ajax. So try counting it within the ajax itself after appending new options

Comment: I had the call to "counter" function outside of the ajax call. Moved it inside and it works perfectly. Lesson of the day, Ajax is asynchronous. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$.ajax({
    url: your_url lead_id,
    type: "your_request_method",
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
                 if(data)
                 {
                     code_to_add_options_to_select

                     var numberOfOptions = $('select#id_of_select option').length;
                 }
                 else
                     alert("An error occurred");
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I did not consider the fact that Ajax is asynchronous. If you're logic depends on the results of an ajax call, it must be within the "success" key/function.